# Time complexity of this unique string algorithm

Tags: string, algorithm, hashmap

I am preparing for an interview and came across a question where you try to find if a string contains all unique characters.

Here is the algorithm I came up with.

```
public static boolean isUniqueChars(String str)
{
    char[] charArray = str.toCharArray();
    Map<Character, Integer> charCounter = new TreeMap<Character, Integer>();

    for (char i : charArray)
    {
        if(charCounter.containsKey(i))
            return false;
        else
            charCounter.put(i,1);
    }
    return true;
}
```

I see one for loop so it's at least O(n). I believe the lookup in hashmap is also O(n). So does that make my algorithm O(n^2)?

And if it is O(n^2), then how is it better than nested for loop where I just compare each char with rest of the array. That'd also be O(n^2).
Thanks

Comment: If lookup in hashing structures was `O(n)`, there would be absolutely no reason to use them since linear search through any set finds all matches in `O(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

`containsKey`'s [time requirement in TreeMap is O(log n)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#get(java.lang.Object)) and [O(1) in HashMap (for `get` anyway)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html). That makes your algorithm's time cost O(n log n). Since you don't need the values in your map, you could use a Set, e.g. HashSet or TreeSet, instead.

Comparing each character with the rest of the string would be better if you didn't want to allocate O(σ) memory (i.e. the size of the alphabet) before finding the first match.

Comment: Thanks, I should use a HashSet instead then. Will that make the algorithm O(n) then? Since get is O(1). thanks

Comment: Just to clarify: dictionaries (i.e. hash maps) offer better `find` complexity than search trees, but search trees maintain an order of the set they manage. If you don't need order, go with hashing.